# New service continuity

Tags: circuit-breaker, breaker-box

This is a new 200 amp main breaker panel service and with no service drop yet.  With main breaker off and with all circuits off I show continuity between neutral and the screw on the breaker when the hot is connected yet no continuity on the breaker without hot leads. This is occurring on several circuits. This does not make sense to me if the breaker are off.  Is this a sign of a defective breaker panel?

Comment: That sounds as if what you think is hot was actually neutral, since neutal and ground do wind up going to the same place... but I have no ecplanation for why a breaker would be on the neutral side of the circuit. Are you sure you're testing what you think you're testing?

Comment: I am going to make more test but all my grounds go to the equipment ground,  all the neutrals (white) go to the neural bar and the hots ( black) go to individual breakers. Furthermore, the neural is bonded to the equipment ground.

Answer (score 3):

This can be happening where you have a load connected to that circuit. For example, if you have a light fixture with a light bulb installed and the wall switch turned on. The light bulb acts as a low-value resistor which your continuity tester is seeing as a short between hot and neutral.

Comment: All I can add is that continuity only show at breakers with a load regardless of breaker position and most importantly there is no continuity at neutral and either of the buss bars on the panel. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

If this wasn't the case, things wouldn't work when the power was on.

If one probe is on the breaker terminal, and the other is on the neutral. You're measuring continuity though the entire circuit. Meaning something is connected to the circuit, and ready to draw current.  This could be any electrical device that is turned on, like a radio, light, etc.

If you want to test the breaker. Touch one probe to the bus bar or ungrounded (hot) terminal, and the other to the screw terminal in the breaker. Toggling the breaker handle, you'll see the breaker open and close.